# How to find first activity in Android?

Tags: android

How can I find out from many class file that the particular file is the activity which was created at the time of creating the project?

Comment: can anyone find which activity class was created at the time of creating new project from this link : http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Contacts/src/com/android/contacts/

Comment: so you dont know which activity was created at the time of creating your project ?

Comment: yes i want to know that activity.

Comment: why? are you just looking for the main entry point of the application?

Comment: yes so i can simply copy that project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is must one Activity as Launcher.

```
 <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

It need to define in **AndroidManifest.xml**  so check your **AndroidManifest.xml** and you could see one launcher activity..

I seen your **AndroidManifest.xml** which you given link in this case may be **DialtactsActivity** or **DialtactsContactsEntryActivity** launcher activity

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to directly download that app? I am not able to get any downloading link over that link.

Comment: yes i want to download that whole app so i don't need to create a new project.

Comment: once again sorry brother i really dont know how to download whole project on single click from that link.....

Comment: What is `menifest.xml`?

Comment: @m0skit0 it's main file of android app.

Comment: That's `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @m0skit0 yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is what you mean:

In your manifest:

```
  <activity android:name=".mainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> //THIS IS MAIN BECAUSE THERE IS INTENT_FILTER
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity1" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />  

    <activity android:name=".Activity12" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity android:name=".Activity123" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity android:name=".MyProfileActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```